# Identify rows where time difference is insufficient SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have reviewed and tried numerous codes samples on the site but am no closer to solving my problem. I think is partly due to my coding skills and partly a limitation of SQL Server 2008R2 lack of LAG.

My table `Clock__Times` has tens of thousands of rows with these columns:

```
EMP_NO, ACCOUNT_DATE, IN_STAMP, OUT_STAMP
```

A row is added when the clock out activity occurs. Potentially multiple rows can be added for a given employee each day. I need to identify rows and count the occasions for an employee within a  given time span (`ACCOUNT_DATE BETWEEN D1 & D2`) when the time between clock out time (`OUT_STAMP`) and the next clock in time (`IN_STAMP`) for that employee is less than X hours but greater than Y hours.

I have tried a variety of `JOIN`s but they are always wrong as I have to compare the `OUT_STAMP` on one row with the `IN_STAMP` of the next row added for the same employee.

The Y value is to avoid clock in and out activity over lunch and would probably have a value of say 2 hours. The X value is to identify employees who do not get sufficient time off between shifts say 10 hours.

I will eventually have to scale this up to identify all employees who within a period of time have had insufficient time off.

Comment: Will your final solution cater for things like lead-time, ie. you arrive at the gates to work at 07:48, but have to walk 15 minutes before you get to your office-building, and thus when you clock in at 08:03, you get additional time credited for the walk? How about people that clock in at 05:00? Will they get some other kind of bonus, such as overtime, because they clock in outside of "normal extended hours"? I ask because I have experience from this kind of system and SQL is not the optimal way to do this if you want all those features.

Comment: Thank you but at the moment - we are not considering this - our clocks are placed close to the working environment and so when somebody is clocked in we assume they are working.  We just need to get an idea from our quite big work force who is not getting sufficient time off  for health and saftey resons.  I agree that SQL is not optimal but that is all I have at present.

Comment: Can employees clock in and out multiple times? not in-out-in-out but in-in-out-out? Will you have data like this in the system? Do you need to handle it "correctly"?

Comment: The situation I believe you are envisaging is handled before the data reaches the db. So it always appears as in-out-in-out.  Any errors regarding forgetting to swipe in or swiping in twice have been cleaned prior to this stage.  An employee could howevr have many rows for the same day and we work around the clock. Its the people who work overtime until beyond midnight and then come back to work at 7am the next day that we need to identify - in case this is happening too much for their safety.

Comment: OK, I'm going to post an answer with what I understand from your question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a trial at a potential solution.

Criteria:

- You have clock-in and clock-out as datetime in your table
- You have multiple employees in the table
- You want to find all occurrences of a clock-out followed by a clock-in (for the same employee) where

  - the diff is greater than 2 hours
  - the diff is less than 10 hours

Here's a full SQL example that creates a sample table with data and the query at the end:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SO23010761')
    DROP TABLE SO23010761
GO

CREATE TABLE SO23010761
(
    emp     INT,
    dt      DATETIME,
    type    CHAR(1)
)
GO

INSERT INTO SO23010761
VALUES
    (1, '2014-01-01 08:00', 'I'),
    (1, '2014-01-01 08:15', 'O'),
    (1, '2014-01-01 10:30', 'I'),
    (1, '2014-01-01 16:00', 'O'),
    (2, '2014-01-01 08:00', 'I'),
    (2, '2014-01-01 08:15', 'O'),
    (2, '2014-01-01 10:30', 'I'),
    (2, '2014-01-01 16:00', 'O')
GO

WITH meta
AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp ORDER BY dt) AS ROWNUM
    FROM
        SO23010761
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            M1.emp,
            M1.dt AS dt_out,
            M2.dt AS dt_in,
            DATEDIFF(MI, M1.dt, M2.dt) AS DIFF
        FROM
            meta M1
            INNER JOIN meta M2
                ON M1.emp = M2.emp
                AND M1.rownum = M2.rownum - 1
        WHERE
            M1.type = 'O'
        AND M2.type = 'I'
    ) AS dummy
WHERE
    DIFF >= 2 * 60
AND DIFF <= 10 * 60
GO
```

This will:

- Create a meta-table that numbers each row for a single employee sequentially
- Join 1 row with the next row (ie. 1 higher row number) for the same employee. Basically, if the rows for an employee are rows A, B, C, D (in that order) you will join A with B, B with C, C with D
- Filter so that we only contain such matches where we have an OUT followed by an IN
- Calculate the diff between the OUT and the IN in minutes
- Select those rows where the diff is greater (or equal to in this case) 2 hours but less than 10.

Comment: Note that DATEDIFF here will do some rounding, so if you need to take seconds into account to get an accurate selection, please change the way to calculate the difference.

Comment: Thank you I am working through your example now.  My data is structured slightly diffeently in that on the one row I have the in time and the out time. As below  [EMP_NO] [varchar](11) NOT NULL,
 [ACCOUNT_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [IN_STAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [OUT_STAMP] [datetime] NULL,

Comment: GREAT thank you that works well - I can evolve it further from here, but you have really made a difference to my day.